# Not sure about some syntax

Tags: lex

It's from Lex,

assuming the definition of lex structure is:

```
... definitions ...
%%
... rules ...
%%
... subroutines ...
```

In one of the example file, I first see the following line from definition PART:

```
  %x PP PRAGMA
```

Then in the RULE PART, i saw:

```
<PP>[ \t\r]*                { }
<PRAGMA>.                   { }
^[ \t]*#[ \t]*version       { BEGIN PP; return VERSION_TOK; }
```

So, here comes my questions(I understand the general concept of lex):

1. what's PP PRAGMA? How should I understand %x?
2. for the RULE PART: what does  and  means? they shouldn't be a token, right?
3. What does BEGIN PP means?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`<PP>` and `<PRAGMA>` are "start conditions". In fact, they're "exclusive" start conditions because they were declare with `%x`. (`%s` would have declared "inclusive" start conditions.)

I don't know why they're called start conditions; the word "start" is a bit confusing. You could think of them as lexical states, but that would also be a bit confusing because "state" usually means something different.

At any moment during the lexical analysis, `lex` has an active "start conditions". Most of the time, the (predefined default) start condition INITIAL is active; that's always the case where you haven't declared any start conditions. You can "enter" a start condition with the macro `BEGIN(CONDITION)`.

Rules starting `<CONDITION>` are only used when CONDITION is the active start condition. A rule can have more than one condition name inside of the angle brackets, or it can have `<*>` (meaning all conditions) or it can have no conditions at all. Rules which don't specify a condition are used whenever the active condition is "inclusive". If the active condition is "exclusive", only rules which specifically name the condition are used (including `<*>` wildcard rules).

Conditions are actually integer constants, and the current condition is the value of YY_START. You can save them away and restore them later, for example, although `lex` provides a convenient condition stack to make that easier.

I believe that the normal definition of BEGIN is:

```
#define BEGIN YY_START =
```

which is why you don't have to put parentheses around the condition name (as in BEGIN PP), but I personally think this is bad style since at least some lex-alikes actually define BEGIN as a macro taking an argument.

Start conditions are really handy, by the way.

Comment: Such a beautiful and clear explanation!! Totally appreciated!!